# Scrapy Can duplicates filter be persistent with Jobs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-pipeline

```py
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item
```

Above code is from Scrapy official website: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
which is used for filtering duplicates.

And as Scrapy documentation suggested, http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html
To pause and resume a spider, I need to use the Jobs system.

So I'm curious if the Scrapy Jobs system can make duplicates filter persistent in its directory. The way that implements the duplicates filter is so simple that I'm in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement your pipeline so that it reads the `JOBDIR` setting and, when that setting is defined, your pipeline:

1. Reads the initial value of `self.ids_seen` from some file inside the `JOBDIR` directory.
2. At run time, it updates that file as new IDs are added to the set.